# DBA to work from home

Tags: career

I was wondering is it feasible or doable to work from home as a DBA or Database designer/developer or Business intelligence developer.
I have seen developers doing great working from home, but can DBAs work from home and be productive or do they have to physically be at work.

- Do you know any DBA working from home.
- If yes how is he managing it and what challenges is he facing
- Is it more productive to work from home as a DBA

Comment: DBA is a broad term that could include responsibilities similar to a SA all the way to responsibilities similar to a developer.  Which responsibilities a given DBA has result in  varying work from home suitability.  By adding Database designer/developer you have broadened the scope even more which could lead to conflicting answers that would both be correct.  I suggest you define as clearly as possible what type of DBA you are asking about.

Comment: I prefer my DBAs to physically crank the database to get it started, so I make them sit close by (with a spare can of oil).  Sometimes I make them take the database home with them to keep it company.

Comment: Just curious, do you believe this question really has much to do with the job itself? Are the answers going to be different if the job title is accountant, customer support rep or unicorn stew chef? What about a DBA's job makes the ability to work from home different than a developer's job?

Comment: This is not a good fit for the Q&A Format here - it's a career AND poll question, where there's no right answer but everyone can post their opinion on the matter and everyone is right.

Answer (score 4):

It depends...

Anyone can work from home if they have the proper work ethic.  If your very self motivated and task oriented then it will work fine.  It is important that you are able to show the people that you report to that you are producing top quality work.

As a manager it is harder for me to manage remote employees because I have to work harder to make a personal connection with them and ensure that we are working well together.  I have some great people that work for me, database professionals, that work from home hundreds of miles away.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, it is quite reasonable to work from home.  I prefer a 50/50 mix of at home work, and in the office work.

When I have to do after-hours work, I do that at home.  If I have some serious development to do that requires good concentration, I will do that from home.

If meetings are scheduled, or if I need to interface with the rest of the team more, then I make a point of going in to the office.

Being able to work from home is a great perk, but work and home life tend to blurr a bit as you end up responding immediately to alerts and/or emails.  But that is the life I have chosen, and I love it.